# Move WPF Window several pixels right

Tags: c#, wpf

How to move a wpf window from c# code? I just dlike to write something like

```
if(condition)
 {
   myWPFWindow.MoveThisWindowSeveralPixelsRight();
 }
```

Comment: `myWPFWindow.Left += SomeNumberOfPixels`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the `Left` value.

```
myWPFWindow.Left += 10;
```

Comment: Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' and 'int'

Comment: @curiousity Do you have a stack panel named "Left"? Did you forget to put the `.Left`? Please show your code, you are missing something, `Left` is not a stack panel, its a window property.

Comment: @RonBeyer is correct. We need to see more code. Your variable type does not seem to be a Window as your question mentioned.  If you have a StackPanel child control you are attempting to move, the code will depend upon it's parent (is it the root object withing the window or a child perhaps?